# Python 3 Get HTTP page

Tags: python, http, python-3.x

How can I get python to get the contents of an HTTP page? So far all I have is the request and I have imported http.client.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Using [`urllib.request`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/urllib.request.html) is probably the easiest way to do this:

```
import urllib.request
f = urllib.request.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com")
print(f.read())
```

Comment: Tried that and I got "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'"

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that you were using Python 3. I've updated my example to match.

Comment: @Davide Gualano: The Python 2.x `urllib2` module has been rolled into the Python 3.x `urllib` set of modules: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

Comment: @Greg: my bad, I didn't read the question title carefully enough :)

Answer (score 14):

**Usage built-in module "http.client"**

```
import http.client

connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.bitbucket.org", timeout=2)
connection.request('GET', '/2.0/repositories')
response = connection.getresponse()
print('{} {} - a response on a GET request by using "http.client"'.format(response.status, response.reason))
content = response.read().decode('utf-8')
print(content[:100], '...')
```

Result:

> 200 OK - a response on a GET request by using "http.client"
>   {"pagelen": 10, "values": [{"scm": "hg", "website": "", "has_wiki":
>   true, "name": "tweakmsg", "links ...

**Usage third-party library "requests"**

```
response = requests.get("https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories")
print('{} {} - a response on a GET request by using "requests"'.format(response.status_code, response.reason))
content = response.content.decode('utf-8')
print(content[:100], '...')
```

Result:

> 200 OK - a response on a GET request by using "requests"
>   {"pagelen": 10, "values": [{"scm": "hg", "website": "", "has_wiki":
>   true, "name": "tweakmsg", "links ...

**Usage built-in module "urllib.request"**

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories")
print('{} {} - a response on a GET request by using "urllib.request"'.format(response.status, response.reason))
content = response.read().decode('utf-8')
print(content[:100], '...')
```

Result:

> 200 OK - a response on a GET request by using "urllib.request"
>   {"pagelen": 10, "values": [{"scm": "hg", "website": "", "has_wiki":
>   true, "name": "tweakmsg", "links ...

Notes:

1. Python 3.4
2. Result from the responses most likely will be differ only content

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the requests library. I found this particularly useful because it was easier to retrieve and display the HTTP header.

```
import requests

source = 'http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/intro-short.txt'

r = requests.get(source)

print('Display actual page\n')
for line in r:
    print (line.strip())

print('\nDisplay all headers\n')
print(r.headers)
```

Comment: Is this Python 3?

Answer (score 1):

pip install requests

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=artist&q=beyonce')
r.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code which can format data for human reading:

```
text = f.read().decode('utf-8')
```