# WinError 10049: The requested address is not valid in its context

Tags: python, sockets, httprequest

I am trying to make a raw HTTP request in Python and write the response to a file. When I try to bind to the resolved IP Address or domain of the host I get this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
> File "thingy.py", line 3, in <module>
>
>   soc.bind(('168.62.48.183', 80))
> ```
>
> OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

I found a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043413/connecting-to-myself-through-my-public-ip-through-tcp) that had the identical error, but it did not answer my question because it was for a *listening* socket. Here is my code:

```
from socket import *
soc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
soc.bind(('168.62.48.183', 80))
soc.send('GET /miners/get?file=BFGMiner-3.99-r.1-win32.zip HTTP/1.1\nUser-Agent:MultiMiner/V3\nHost: www.multiminerapp.com\n')
response = soc.recv()
respfile = open("http-response.txt","w")
respfile.writelines(response)
respfile.close()
```

Answer (score 19):

```
from socket import *
soc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
soc.connect(('168.62.48.183', 80))
soc.send('GET /miners/get?file=BFGMiner-3.99-r.1-win32.zip HTTP/1.1\nUser-Agent:MultiMiner/V3\nHost: www.multiminerapp.com\n')
with open("http-response.txt","w") as respfile:
    response = soc.recv(1024) # <--- Use select.epoll or asyncore instead!
    respfile.writelines(response)
```

The reason for why your code fails tho is because you're trying to bind to an external IP.
Your machine is not aware of this IP hence the error message, if you'd change it to say `127.0.0.1` it would work, but then again you would need a `.listen(4)` and `ns, na = soc.accept()` before utelizing `.send()` and your `soc.recv()` would need to be `ns.recv(1024)`.

In other words, you mixed up client sockets with server sockets and you're **binding** to a IP not present on the local machine.

**Also note**: `soc.recv()` will fail, you need a buffer-size argument like so: `soc.recv(1024)`

## Python3:

```
from socket import *
soc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
soc.connect(('168.62.48.183', 80))
soc.send(b'GET /miners/get?file=BFGMiner-3.99-r.1-win32.zip HTTP/1.1\nUser-Agent:MultiMiner/V3\nHost: www.multiminerapp.com\n\n') # Note the double \n\n at the end.
with open("http-response.txt","wb") as respfile:
    response = soc.recv(8192)
    respfile.write(response)
```

There's two major differences, we send a binary `GET /miners/..` string rather than a standard string.
Secondly we open the output-file in a binary form because the data recieved will also be in binary form..

This is because Python no longer decodes the string for you because of a number of reasons, so you need to either treat the data as binary or manually decode it along the way.

## You should probably:

```
import urllib.request
f = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.multiminerapp.com/miners/get?file=BFGMiner-3.99-r.1-win32.zip")
print(f.read())
```

Comment: also, `socket.recv()` does not exist, it needs a buffersize as argument.

Comment: @mata Correct, will add that in there.

Comment: If I put a buffer size of, say 1024, and the response is, say 80 megabytes, will it put the entire response in the variable or will it only the buffer size? Also:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "thingy.py", line 4, in <module>
    soc.send('GET /miners/get?file=BFGMiner-3.99-r.1-win32.zip HTTP/1.1\nUser-Ag
ent: MultiMiner/V3\nHost: www.multiminerapp.com\n')
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

Comment: @user3451109 ofcourse not, this is why you either use `select.epoll` or `asyncore`, or just a standard HTTP lib like [urllib.request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023893/python-3-get-http-page)

Comment: @user3451109 You **need** to specify if you're using Python3 or Python2 when it comes to sockets, because Python3 has gone over to utelizing binary data in all sorts of IO operations instead of trying to convert the data for you. See my edit...

Comment: @Torxed: Thanks for pointing us in the right direction: "The reason for why your code fails tho is because you're trying to bind to an external IP."

Answer (score 8):

First, you must connect both devices to the same network. Then, for the server.py (or anything you want to call it)

Use

```
soc.bind(('', PORT))
```

Instead of

```
soc.bind(('IP', PORT))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: When you  creating a server with python, the first field of soc.bind need be a empty string.

Comment: and what to write to the client?

Answer (score 0):

Create a server using third party softwares like xamp, wamp

then,

```
 soc.bind(('server_ip',port_number))
```