# How resolve that python error WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get an error at line listener.bind(("192.168.10.5", 4444)):

> OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

Python code:

```
#!usr/bin/python
import socket
listener=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listener.setsocket(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listener.bind(("192.168.10.5", 4444))
listener.listen(0)
print("[+] waiting for incoming connections")
listener.accept()
print("[+] Got a connection")
```

**Error**

```
listener.bind(("192.168.10.5", 4444))
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WinError 10049: The requested address is not valid in its context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857942/winerror-10049-the-requested-address-is-not-valid-in-its-context)

Comment: no one work for me