# Why cant my friend not connect to my socket

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

so im trying to establish  connection between my friends pc and my pc but it keeps saying the host failed to respond
this is the client

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect(("192.168.0.177", 1234))

msg = s.recv(1024)
print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

and this is the server

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET
, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('192.168.0.177', 1234))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f'conection from {address} has bene establish')
    clientsocket.send(bytes("welcome to the server", "utf-8"))
```

Update/Edit
so i tried my public IP address and it says
WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
the error is serverside

Comment: Is your friend on the same LAN as you?

Comment: no he is at his house

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, you say that your friend is on a different LAN as you.  The reason that he can not reach your server is because he is trying to reach your server `on your LAN` by connecting to an address (192.168.0.177) in the 192.168.x.x. space `from his LAN`.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network, where it explains that addresses in the 192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255 range are reserved for private networks.  As such, `IP packets originating from or addressed to a private IP address cannot be routed through the public Internet`.

To solve this problem, you should setup a [port-forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) rule your router, to forward incoming connections to port 1234 on the `public` side of your router to 192.168.0.177:1234 on the `private` side of your router.  Then, your friend should connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1234, where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the `public` IP address of your router.  You can find the public ip address of your router by pointing your web browser to [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com) from a computer on your LAN.  If the port-forwarding is working correctly, your router should forward the incoming connection from your friend to your server at 192.168.0.177:1234 running on your private LAN.

Answer (score 0):

The IP range `192.168.0.0` to `192.168.255.255` (192.168.0.0/16) is considered to be the private range. Even if you design your routers to force the packets from these sources to the outside internet world, other routers will be discarding the packets.

You need to have both the machines on the same LAN or you need to set up a network on your own and configure routers (routing tables) in between or a public IP for accepting connections.

Comment: i setup a protforward thats what teh 192.168.0.177 is

Comment: @HyperStrike1212 You are having ``192.168.0.177`` behind a router which has public IP?

Comment: no i setup a protforward that i have used in teh past for mc servers etc and thats the ip i gave him

Comment: @HyperStrike1212 Ok on which machine you setup port-forward, on machine ``192.168.0.177`` or some other machine which is publicly accessible?

Comment: its hosted on my pc

Comment: @HyperStrike1212: Your port forward may be correct but the client must connect to the **public IP address** of your router, not 192.168.0.177.

Comment: when i put my routers ip it says [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

Comment: @HyperStrike1212 After a quick Googling, I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857942/winerror-10049-the-requested-address-is-not-valid-in-its-context  Seems like you changed the IP you are binding the server to an external IP. You dont need to change the server code. In the client instead of 192.168.0.177 you need to have router public IP. If all other things are correct, you are good to go :)

Comment: @HyperStrike1212 Yes it gives, because you are trying to bind to an external IP in your server. With server code unchanged and in client code changing ``connect(("192.168.0.177"....)`` to ``connect(("router ip"....)`` still gives the error?

Comment: @HyperStrike1212 Please edit the question to update your progress and attach the errors you are getting So that community will be interested in solving your problem. Just saying you got the error without greater details is not an easy way of explaining you problems. You need to be specific where you got the error, in client ? in server ? and what error is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216838/discussion-between-hyper-strike1212-and-mohith-reddy).